# Error updating UICollectionView with performBatchUpdates:completion:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am experimenting with `UICollectionView` in one of my apps. When I add an item to the collection view I get an error:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
 reason: 'must return a UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes instance from -layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:
 for path <NSIndexPath 0x10486f40> 2 indexes [0, 0]'
```

Here is how I add an item to the collection view and update it (in `viewWillAppear:`):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.moc = [[AZStackifyDataModel shareDataModel] mainContext];
    [AZUser getAllUsersUsingManagedObjectContext:self.moc
         success:^(NSArray *users) {
             [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
                 self.collectionData = [users mutableCopy];

                 NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
                 for (int i = 0; i < self.collectionData.count; i++) {
                     [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
                 }

                 [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
             } completion:nil];
         }
         failure:^(NSError *error) {

         }];
}
```

If I replace the call to `performBatchUpdates:completion:` by this code, everything works fine:

```
self.collectionData = [users mutableCopy];
[self.collectionView reloadData];
```

Does anybody know what is wrong with my code please?

**Note:** I have subclassed `UICollectionViewCell`, but I don't think that this is the problem since `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` is not even called/reached when the app crashes...

**Edit 1:** Here is the full view controller and the custom collection view cell: https://gist.github.com/AzizLight/4396a9cfe10511e59988

If you need even more code please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Can you show your code for `-layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:`? The first place to look should be where the exception tells you to look!

Comment: I haven't implemented/overriden `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath`...

Comment: Which UICollectionViewLayout are you using?

Comment: I am using the Flow layout, which is the default. When I added the collection view to my view controller I barely touched anything.